# Aqua Data Studio - Executing Script/Retrieving Rows

Tags: c#, oracle, datatable, cursor, dataset

I have a stored procedure stored in an Oracle 11g Database which I make calls to from C#. This call returns a System.Data.DataSet via the use of an OUT cursor in PL/SQL.

My question lies in how Aqua Data Studio behaves when scripting an EXECUTE BIND. I frequently use this functionality for debugging.

When I make a call from C#, the DataSet is returned in roughly 20 - 30 seconds. I then generally use a DataSet visualisation tool to perform checks/testing (Which takes just a few seconds to load). When I am debugging in ADS and use an EXECUTE BIND to return the Data to the output window in ADS I am presented with the following in the notification bar above the output window as it executes:

```
    1. 'Executing script ... [Time: ##s]'
    2. 'Retrieving row #### for statement (1 of 1) ... [Time: #m ##s]'
```

Step 2 takes several minutes, which is far longer than I'd expect. I understand that there is some overhead in visualising this data set, but is there something else going on behind the scenes here? And is there a quicker way to debug/visualise data sets from within aqua data studio?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you right click on the Stored Procedure and select Debug in Procedure Debugger and let me know if this takes time to debug as well ?